# How to find full process arguments and associated listening ports?

Tags: linux, bash, netstat, ps, lsof

I can execute `netstat -atulpn | grep java` to find all Java processes with their accompanying ports, which is great, however I would like to also have the processes full execution arguments also shown.  I don't believe that this is possible with `netstat` from everything I've explored so far and so I was thinking that I would have to write a script to process the output of `netstat` and then pass the pids into `ps` and then prettify the output to show the ip+port and full command line.

Is there a better way of doing this or is this about the only option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ss -lnptu piped to awk with a call to ps -p. I'm on a mobile device, so it is a little tricky to type out a full example at the moment.

Listening Sockets:

```
ss -lnptu | awk 'NR>1 { split($7,p,","); printf "Listen: "$5 " Command: "; system("ps --no-headers -o args p "p[2]); }'
```

All Sockets (will likely require some additional filtering due to sockets without process information in TIME_WAIT, etc):

```
ss -anptu state listening state established state connected state unconnected | grep -v TIME_WAIT | awk 'NR>1 { split($7,p,","); printf "Listen: "$5 " Command: "; system("ps --no-headers -o args p "p[2]); }'
```

Comment: Thanks for heads up Mark, looking forward to a more detailed response!

Comment: @ylluminate I added a quick and dirty example.

Comment: Great, thanks yes.  Just FYI on CentOS 6.5 it gave me some funky output regarding the arguments that are being passed in: https://gist.github.com/8a36dbbc3fe9c8371742

Comment: @ylluminate I tested with Ubuntu 13.04 (ss --version = iproute2-ss130716). Can you give me an example line of output from ss -anptu on your system?

Comment: Sure, here's the raw output: http://j.mp/1dPtubZ (Apologize, I made it on a wide terminal.)

Comment: @ylluminate The issue is that sockets in TIME-WAIT, FIN-WAIT-1, and such do not have process information to display (and the one-liner I posted was not written particularly robustly). If you run ss -lnptu instead of ss -anptu it should work as those records would be omitted.

Comment: Thanks, it certainly can be cleaned up some more, but this worked just fine.  I did `2>/dev/null` it to remove a lot of extra warnings/errors coming off and I `grep`'d and `grep -v`'d some of the content out to filter it better.  Thanks!

Comment: I get "error: list of process IDs must follow p".

Answer (score 2):

I was getting errors from `ps` on Ubuntu 16.04 when using Mark Sturgill's answer as-is. Needed a slight modification to make it work: basically added an extra `split` to further isolate the numeric PID from the joined format that `ss` returns (e.g. `pid=1306 -> 1306`). I also added the `-ww` flag to make ps output the full args:

```sh
ss -lnptu | awk 'NR>1 { split($7,p,","); split(p[2],pid,"="); printf "Listen: "$5 " Command: "; system("ps --no-headers -ww -o args p "pid[2]); }'
```

Comment: Also note that the command explodes with IPv6 so as workaround you can add a `-4` in your `ss` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

@ylluminate, for CentOS change it to `ss -lnptu | awk 'NR>1 { split($6,p,","); printf "Listen: "$4 " Command: "; system("ps --no-headers -o args p "p[2]); }'`